# install oracle data integrator on mac book pro

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

Hi can someone provide detailed installation steps to install Oracle data integrator 11g or 12c on my mac book pro. I am very new to Mac and I am a business analyst, so would appreciate if you could be specific in giving the instructions.

Answer (score 3):

ODI can be run in OS X.

Today I have installed ODI 12c2.1.3 version in my macbook pro.
For sure, there is no information is available to fix the issues. I hope this will help others.

As we know the default installation directly doesn't work. I have done some changes in default configurations and lib. I am running setup on jdk8. I am assuming you have already installed ODI

**Changes you have to made is as follows**

**odi.conf**
File Path - <Oracle Home>/Middleware/Oracle_Home/odi/studio/bin
Append the below lines to odi.conf 
AddVMOption  -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel  
AddJavaLibFile ../extensions/oracle.odi.navigator.12/lib/jide-common.jar

Download the latest jidesoft demo zip from http://www.jidesoft.com/products/download.htm
Link I have used - http://www.jidesoft.com/products/1.4/jide_demo.zip
extract the zip file and rename the file to jide-common.jar and copy it to location
<Oracle Home>/Middleware/Oracle_Home/odi/studio/extensions/oracle.odi.navigator.12/lib

After this go to
cd <Oracle Home>/Middleware/Oracle_Home/odi/studio/bin/
./odi -verbose

You should not see any error.
As this jidesoft jar is an evaluation version. you should follow their terms and conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer saved me from certain stress

Comment: Well I can understand. Not an easy solution is available for this. I had put lots of effort to get this working. so should be share with others ☺️

Answer (score 1):

ODI Studio 11g can be installed on Mac OS X by [downloading the Oracle Data Integrator **Companion**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/data-integrator/downloads/index.html). I'm not sure it's the most reliable way to use ODI though.

You will first need that you have the right version of Java installed. You can check on the [certification matrix](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/fusion-certification-100350.html) and if needed install a new JDK.

Then unzip the companion archive, browse to the *studio* folder, unzip the other archive in there, browse to *oracledi/client* and start odi.sh. There might be a dialog box asking for the location of the JDK on the first start.

ODI Studio 12c doesn't run on OS X so far.

If the goal is just to try ODI and quickly learn it, I actually would rather recommend to download the free [ODI Getting Started Virtual Machine](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/data-integrator/odi-demo-2032565.html) that runs on Virtual Box. Everything will already be set up with an Oracle database, Golden Gate and much more.